# How to restart thread or any other alternate solution

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, audio

I am working calling app which automatically calls a number. I am using main thread to query call status(busy,dialing,active, calling, deactivated etc). Whenever call is picked recorded audio will be played using other thread 2. When call status is deactivated main thread will stop audio by stopping thread 2. On next call again when call is picked recorded audio will played using thread 2.

```
     Thread autoReminder = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadAutoCalling));


////   Main thread on call attend calls
 autoReminder.Start();
// On call end, i tried
 autoReminder.Abort();

  private void threadAutoCalling()
        {
            try
            {
               // PlayAudio(@"C:\Users\CheatnPc\Desktop\TextToSpeechAudio\psf1.wav");

                PlayAudio(@"C:\Users\CheatnPc\Desktop\TextToSpeechAudio\psf3.wav");
                PlayAudio(@"C:\Users\CheatnPc\Desktop\TextToSpeechAudio\sales.wav");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
 public void PlayAudio(string path)
    {

        (new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Audio()).Play(path, Microsoft.VisualBasic.AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete);

    }
```

after thread abort it can not be started again. How can i do this or is there any alternate solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Thread's cannot be restarted - when they're done, they're done.

The usual solution would be to simply start a new thread, but when you're doing as little as you are, using a threadpool thread might be a better idea:

```
Task.Run(threadAutoCalling);
```

Or even better, if there's an asynchronous way of invoking those `PlaySound` and `Speak`, use that - usually, you wouldn't need *real* CPU work to handle operations like that.

Comment: can you please share any example of asynchronous way of invoking .

Comment: how to stop the task when call is disconnected.

Comment: @HotCoolStud No, I have no idea what APIs you are using. You will have to consult the documentation. And no, there is no way to stop a task - but there isn't a way to stop a thread either, so you could just use a `CancellationToken` to provide custom cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood correctly you want to abort your play of music. For this reason it is more applicable `Task` class. You can cancel your `Task` by calling  `Cancel()` method of class `CancellationTokenSource`.

Example of console application:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource =
        new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
   while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      ThreadAutoCalling();
   }
   token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}, token);
try
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to abort the task");
      Console.ReadLine();
      cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
      task.Wait();
   }
catch (AggregateException e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
}
```

Comment: I am playing sound in Microsoft.VisualBasic.AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete so that next audio will played once current is completed. Cancel.task() will not be completed till threadAutoCalling() is completed.